# javascript file doesn't work for ckeditor generated with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I generate ckeditor textarea with php and ajax and ckeditor javascript files include in main html file, already php and ajax work correctly but ckeditor doesn't display in form and display simple textarea without eceditor toolbars.

ajax code:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
    data: "book="+book_arzyabi,
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(response){

        $('#resp').html(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open");

});
```

php code:

```
    echo '<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="fname" name="fname" rows="10" >test</textarea>';
```

html code:

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ckeditor/sample.js" ></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form>
 <fieldset>
 <label for="name">Name</label>
 <div id="resp" ></div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me for resolve problem.

Comment: whats your ajax response containing?

Comment: ajax response contains textarea: echo '<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="fname" name="fname" rows="10" >test</textarea>';

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind `ckeditor` in the success handler of ajax,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reg_arz_ajax2.php",
    data: "book=" + book_arzyabi,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        $('#resp').html(response);
        $(".ckeditor").ckeditor();
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //On error, we alert user
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```